# Bamboo exception: invalid path for remote github repository being loaded

Tags: path, duplicates, repository, bamboo

Does anyone had this issue before in Bamboo? invalid path for remote github repository being loaded;

com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.git.GitCommandException: command [C:\development\tools\git\cmd\git.exe -c credential.helper= -c 'credential.helper=store --file=C:/DEVELO~1/tools/ATLASS~1.2/ATLASS~1.2/temp/GITCRE~1.TMP' ls-remote https://uteachon-codes@github.com/uteachon-codes/uteachon-codes/ems-app.git] failed with code 128. Working directory was [C:\development\tools\atlassian-bamboo-7.2.2\atlassian-bamboo-7.2.2\temp]., stderr:
remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/uteachon-codes/uteachon-codes/ems-app.git/' not found
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.git.GitCommandProcessor.runCommand(GitCommandProcessor.java:740)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.git.GitCommandProcessor.getRemoteRefs(GitCommandProcessor.java:501)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.git.NativeGitOperationHelper.lambda$getRemoteRefs$1(NativeGitOperationHelper.java:612)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.CallableResultCache$1.load(CallableResultCache.java:39)
at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.CallableResultCache$1.load(CallableResultCache.java:35)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)

Answer (score 0):

Look the url that git is trying to clone:
https://github.com/uteachon-codes/uteachon-codes/uteachon-codes/ems-app.git
Has the "uteachon-codes" duplicated.
I think the real is "https://github.com/uteachon-codes/uteachon-codes/ems-app.git".

Comment: It is not duplicating anymore via Linked repositories section. Resolved.